# Consulta sql lanza error: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

estoy con esta consulta en postgress:

```
SELECT f.*, f.id as identificador, usuarios.* 
FROM usuarios 
JOIN feeds f ON usuarios.id = f.usuariosid 
where usuarios.id='1' 
or  usuarios.id IN (select seguidor_id from seguidores where usuario_id=1) 
and f.created_at < (select fecha_seguimiento from seguidores 
    where usuario_id=1);
```

Me arroja el error:  ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Se que el error esta en el final de la sentencia, puesto que devuelve mas de un valor, pero quiero utilizar el operador "<" y no se como hacerlo junto al operador in.

Al final quiero que esa consulta me devuelva las publicaciones (created_at de un usuario a partir de que son amigos (fecha seguimiento), por eso el operador menor que...

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es "created_at de un usuario a partir de que son amigos (fecha seguimiento" deberías ponerle un `MIN` a la fecha de seguimiento, te devolverá la fecha en la que empezaron a ser amigos, que me imagino es la que buscas.

```
SELECT f.*, f.id as identificador, usuarios.* 
FROM usuarios 
JOIN feeds f ON usuarios.id = f.usuariosid 
where usuarios.id='1' 
or  usuarios.id IN (select seguidor_id from seguidores where usuario_id=1) 
and f.created_at < (select MIN(fecha_seguimiento) from seguidores 
    where usuario_id=1);
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por su respuesta. ¿Eso me arrojaría la fecha mínima de todos los seguidores, no? pero no de cada seguidor. La idea es que si el usuario A, empieza a seguir a B, solo vea los feeds de este a partir de que se han hecho amigos, posteriormente si sigue al usuario C, la fecha que devuelve será la de seguimiento del usuario B, y por tanto, podría ver todas las publicaciones de C, aunque no fueren amigos.

Gracias, por su tiempo.

Comment: ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?